# PF rule for Continuity

Tags: firewall, mac-osx, pf, rules

So it looks like the Continuity on OS X 10.10 creates network interface on the fly (utun2 here) and my PF blocks it, so that I can't make/answer calls.

I'm not an admin, just use the IceFloor for PF config. Do you know what's the easiest way to configure PF without turning it completely off? Can I just say "allow all in/out for any utun[NUM]"?

Thanks